# If refresh does not work then try again loop: Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

Tags: vba

I have a VBA macro with the following line of code that pulls data using a data connection to a website:

```
Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

Every time the internet stops working (even momentarily) the macro goes into debug mode and I get a message box warning that the query was not able to refresh.  This is extremely disruptive.  Instead, I would like to enter a loop that keeps attempting to refresh the query.  The loop would end if the query is successful (i.e., no error).